# MySQL query: Order by priority index and prevent large groups of categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this one:

```
id name      category oindex
1  product1  cat1     3
2  product2  cat1     5
3  product3  cat2     1
4  product4  cat1     2
5  product5  cat4     1
```

The *oindex* column is a valuation of the product, from 1 to 5 (less to more important), the rest is pretty verbose i suppose.

I want to SELECT the whole table order by the oindex so the top quality products comes in the first positions but I don't want to have many consecutive products from the same category. For example if you Select and Order by oindex, you'll get product2 and product1 in the first two positions but they belong to the same category so is not correct to have 2 consecutive from the same one. Ideally it should take product2 and then product4 and then return to product1.

How would you approach the problem?

Comment: just write a sample showing  your wished result

Comment: This site deals with *specific* programming question and requires that you post code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY category ORDER BY oindex
```